# How do I open geotiff images with GDAL in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import sys

# This allows GDAL to throw Python exceptions
src_ds = gdal.Open("fused.tif")
src_ds.show()
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ".../gdalopen1.py", line 5, in module src_ds.show()
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Seems like "show" doesn't exist for this object. On [this](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) page, they open a `*.tif` image and then `print gtif.GetMetadata()`. Does that work for you?

Comment: What are you expecting the `.show()` method to do? Draw the raster? Why? Where did you see documentation for this method? The `.Open` method *has* opened the raster - successfully. Now what do you want to do with it?

Comment: We need to read the images and to display the fused geotiff image in python. can you explain how to read an image in array

Answer (score 10):

The following code opens a raster file and reads a band of the raster into a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array.

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('input.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
img_array = rb.ReadAsArray()
```

Comment: @kalemulaaditya `ds` is `NoneType` because the file was not opened correctly. The most likely reason is the filename that is passed as a parameter to `gdal.Open` is incorrect or the absolute path needs to be given.

Answer (score 8):

You have already opened the dataset, as [Spacedman answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996079/how-do-i-open-geotiff-images-with-gdal-in-python/42000573#comment71170828_41996079). GDAL is not a visualization library (at its core).

You can read the data with:

```
data = src_ds.ReadAsArray()
```

And then pass it on the your favourite plotting library.

Alternatively you could simply output to a more common 'picture' format (PNG for example), and use any viewer you like to display the result.

```
vmin = 0 # minimum value in your data (will be black in the output)
vmax = 1 # minimum value in your data (will be white in the output)
ds = gdal.Translate('fused.png', 'fused.tif', format='PNG', outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, scaleParams=[[vmin,vmax]])
ds = None
```

The scaling is necessary to convert your data values to the 8-bit range (0-255) which commonly used for pictures.

Comment: The error is getting as 

'module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 7'

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by following.

```
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
ds = gdal.Open('Your Geotif image')
band = ds.getRasterBand(1)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42856964/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).