# GeoTIFF software generation

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I have some data about the height of a set of points (for example, from the Google Elevation API). There is a task to save this data in GeoTIFF format, then to use in osgEarth (GDAL). How can this be done? It does not matter in what language.

A quick search on the Internet only gave me the answer to the reverse question ([How do I open geotiff images with gdal in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996079/how-do-i-open-geotiff-images-with-gdal-in-python))

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i would do this with GDAL from python (You could also use [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) which is a nice wrapper around gdal for file raster file handling)

You should put your data in a numpy array,let us call it `some_nparray`.

Then create the tif dataset `gtiffDriver.Create()`. Here you can provide the name of your file, the dimensions in number of columns and rows of your image, the number of bands (here 1), and the datatype. Here i said float32, however byte, int16 etc could also work, depending on your data (you can check it with heigh_data_array.dtype)

Next you should set the geotransform, which is the information about the corner coordinates and pixel resolution, and you should set the projection you are using. This is done with `dataset.SetGeoTransform` and `dataset.SetProjection`. How these are created is not in the scope of this question I believe. If you do not need it, i guess you can even skip that part.

Finally write your array to the file with `WriteArray` and close the file.

You code should look something like this. Here I use the convention that variables prefixed with **some_** should be provided by you.

```
    from osgeo import gdal

    height_data_array = some_nparray

    gtiffDriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')

    dataset = gtiffDriver.Create('result.tif', 
                                 height_data_array.shape[1], 
                                 height_data_array.shape[0], 
                                 1, 
                                 gdal.GDT_Float32)

    dataset.SetGeoTransform(some_geotrans)
    dataset.SetProjection(some_projection)

    dataset.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(height_data_array)
    dataset = None
```